# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState in FragmentTabHost in activity creation

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to use FragmentTabHost in a Fragment from v4 support library inside FragmentActivity. This exception is thrown in the Activity OnCreate while debugging as Alex has pointed out for possible condition, but still committing the fragment transaction in the activity oncreate. Because of this exception my activity is shown with empty tabcontent with tabs.

Note:-
1)I have locked screen rotation - no orientation condition.
2)This happens in the activity oncreate that is in the initial statges
3)I have using commit() in the Activity OnCreate()
4)As log points the commit relation is done in the TabHost not from my side.

here is my log:-

```
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1361)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:282)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:9924)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2198)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2206)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2206)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2206)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2206)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2206)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2206)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2585)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-29 11:32:55.975: E/AndroidRuntime(27470):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**This is my code**

Activity:

```
private void addFragmentToStack(int originCurrentSplitNo, boolean isOrgin,
            int holderId) {

        // Instantiate a new fragment(FragmentTabhost as the layout of this).
        SplitFragment newFragment = SplitFragment.newInstance();


        // Add the fragment to the activity, pushing this transaction
        // on to the back stack.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(holderId, (Fragment) newFragment,
                newFragment.getCurrentFragmentTag());
        if (null == fragmentTagHolder) {
            fragmentTagHolder = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    //tag holders in the activity
        fragmentTagHolder.add(newFragment.getCurrentFragmentTag());
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Fragment that has FragmentTabHost that will be attached to the activity

//SplitFragment.java

```
private View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            // Currently in a layout without a container, so no
            // reason to create our view.
            return null;
        }


        View fragmentTabHostView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_host_layout, container,
                false);
        initFrgmentTab(fragmentTabHostView );
        return fragmentTabHostView;
    }

    private View initFrgmentTab(View oemView) {
        if (null == fragmentTabHostView ) {
            return null;
        }

        typeViewHost = (FragmentTabHost) fragmentTabHostView 
                .findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        if (!(null == typeViewHost)) {

            typeViewHost.setup(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getChildFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);

            LinkedHashMap<Integer, fragmentTabContent> frgmentTabContent = ((OEMCarInspectionActivity) getActivity())
                    .getfrgmentTabContent Details();
    Set<Integer> views = frgmentTabContent .getKeySet();
    //Creating the tabs
            for (Integer viewCode : views) {
                fragmentTabContent carView = carTypeViews.get(viewCode );
                String tabTitle = fragmentTabContent.getViewDescription();

                if (null == tabTitle || tabTitle .trim().isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }
                Bundle tabViewBundle = new Bundle();
                carViewBundle.putInt(CarViewFragment.CARVIEW_CODE_KEY,
                        viewCode);
                typeViewHost.addTab(typeViewHost.newTabSpec(tabTitle )
                        .setIndicator(tabTitle ), TabViewFragment.class,
                        tabViewBundle);

            }
}
```

Fragment to be acting as the tabcontent for the FragmentTabHost:

```
//TabViewFragment.java
/**
     * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its instance number.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (null == container) {
            // Currently in a layout without a container, so no
            // reason to create our view.
            return null;
        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view_layout, container,
                false);

        return v;
    }
```

Layout of FragmentTabHost:

```
//fragment_tab_host_layout.xml(layout for SplitFragment.java )

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally I thought this was most likely a rotation issue. But with your additional details I think I see the problem.

You are initializing your tabhost in a fragment onCreateView. In onCreateView the fragment hasn't yet been added to an activity; it is just being *asked* to provide it's layout. It is likely that the session state hasn't been restored yet (as far as the fragment transaction manager is concerned) as it is essentially in the middle of *building* the state (is inserting the views).

Try moving your tabhost init code to onActivityCreated, which is called after the view is inserted.
I.E:

```
private View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            // Currently in a layout without a container, so no
            // reason to create our view.
            return null;
        }


        View fragmentTabHostView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_host_layout, container,
                false);

        return fragmentTabHostView;
    }

public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       initFrgmentTab(getView());
}
```

If that still throws hissy-fits, the try moving it to onResume (which is certainly after the state has been restored).

Comment: Thnxs for the reply, I think i have not provided the all info previously but now i have updated along with the Note.

Comment: The "Quick" fix would be to use "ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();" instead of "ft.commit();" but I suspect there will be underlying problems with that approach.

Comment: It only will avoid throwing the exception but will not solve the problem.But any how the exception is thrown by the TabHost and internally the tabhost does ft.commit().

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this:

1. Copy all the code of FragmentTabHost.
2. Paste it in a new class inside your project and name it MyTabHost
3. Replace all the commit() in the code to commitAllowStateLoss()
4. Use this class - MyTabHost in your project instead of FragmentTabHost.

It is ugly as hell but it works.